# SWR not pulling from cache

Tags: reactjs, typescript, swr

I've got a pretty basic component that does pagination. If I move pages, I'm trying to get SWR to pull from cache, but it does another api request instead.

Here is a Code.io sample.
https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-elgamal-v9sm9k?file=/src/App.js

If you look at the network tab after going to page 2, and back to page 1, it re-fetches page 1 from the api.

```
export const Stocks: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  interface SearchResponse {
    Response: APIResponse<Array<string>>;
    SearchText: string;
  }
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState<number>(1);

  const stocks = useRequest<Array<StockItem>>(`get-symbols?page=${pageIndex}`);

  const RenderSymbols = () => {
    console.log(stocks);
    if (stocks?.data == undefined) return;
    return stocks.data.map((f, index) => {
      return (
        <Stock key={index} item={f} />
      );
    })
  }
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={12} xl={12}>
        <Typography variant='h4'>Stocks</Typography>
        <Grid container spacing={5}>
          {RenderSymbols()}
        </Grid>
        <Page page={pageIndex} totalItems={stocks.totalRecords} itemsPerPage={9} pageChanged={(p) => setPageIndex(p)} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default Stocks;
```

Anytime I go to the next page in the grid, it increment pageIndex, and SWR gets called here.

```
export default function useRequest<T>(url: string | null): Response<T> {
  
  const config: SWRConfiguration = {
    revalidateOnFocus: false,
  };

  const { data, mutate, error } = useSWR<APIResponse<T>>(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL ?? ""}${url}`,fetcher,config);
  return {
    data: data?.data,
    isLoading: !error && !data,
    isError: error,
    mutate: mutate,
    page: data?.page ?? 0,
    totalRecords: data?.totalRecords ?? 0,
  };
}
```

Here is my fetcher:

```
 export default async function fetcher<JSON = any>(
    input: RequestInfo,
    init?: RequestInit
  ): Promise<JSON> {

    const res = await fetch(`${input}`)

    return res.json()
  }
```

Going back and forth between pages calls a new HTTP request, rather than grabbing it from SWR cache. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong here, just not sure what.

Answer (score 3):

SWR most certainly still uses the cached data (in SWR terms, the "stale data"). It's just that while using the stale data, it does a real request to retrieve the most updated data in the background, then updating it.

That's the main job of SWR, as stated in their [home page](https://swr.vercel.app/):

> SWR is a strategy to first return the data from cache (stale), then send the fetch request (revalidate), and finally come with the up-to-date data.

To prevent fetching newer data and use only stale data, turn the [`revalidateIfStale`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/options#options) option off.

```js
useSWR(url, fetcher, {
  ...config,
  revalidateIfStale: false  // default is `true`
});
```

Depending on your use cases, you probably want these options off too:

- `revalidateOnMount`
- `revalidateOnFocus`
- `revalidateOnReconnect`

As the other answer said, you can also use [`useSWRImmutable`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#disable-automatic-revalidations), which turns all the above options off automatically for you.

Comment: I've tried the exact same thing while just replacing useSWR with SWRImmutable, and it still does the fetch. So I'm not sure what the deal is there.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to revalidate the data at all it's better to use `useSWRImmutable` ([more](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#disable-automatic-revalidations)).

If you just want to increase cache TTL then you need to look into `dedupingInterval` option which is by default only equals to 2000ms

Comment: I've tried the exact same thing while just replacing useSWR with SWRImmutable, and it still does the fetch. So I'm not sure what the deal is there. –

Comment: How does your fetcher function look like? Or can you make a reproduction on https://codesandbox.io? You can use some fake api like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/guide/

Comment: I've added my fetcher to my original post.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-elgamal-v9sm9k?file=/src/App.js

If you look at the network tab after going back and forth between pages, you can see it's fetching again.

Comment: @Dylan You imported regular default import of `swr` package. To import immutable version use `import useSWRImmutable from "swr/immutable"`